# Quotes on :finder_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model with some relationship that is best described if I write my own SQL. To simplify, I write something like this (in, say MyModel.rb):

```
has_many :platform_spots, :finder_sql => "SELECT * FROM platform_spots WHERE id=#{id}"
```

in the model description.

If I now run rails console, and try to pull

```
MyModel.find(:first)
```

I get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `id' for #<Class:0x000001039e4b80>
```

I figure its because I need to use single quotes, so I change it to

```
has_many :platform_spots, :finder_sql => 'SELECT * FROM platform_spots WHERE id=#{id}'
```

Now, in the console

```
ecs = MyModel.find(:first)
ecs.platform_spots
```

I get the errors

```
  PlatformSpot Load (0.2ms)  SELECT * FROM platform_spots WHERE id=#{id}
Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1: SELECT * FROM platform_spots WHERE id=#{id}
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1: SELECT * FROM platform_spots WHERE id=#{id}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [finder\_sql does not parse string with Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545360/finder-sql-does-not-parse-string-with-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting it like this:

```
has_many :platform_spots, :class_name => "PlatformSpot",
            :finder_sql => proc {"select * from platform_spots where id = #{id}"}
```

Comment: Why do I need `:class_name => "PlatformSpot"`?

Comment: You don't, just wanted to show that it's available as an option if you need to specify a different class name, i removed it.

Comment: No, I agree, it's good for informational purposes. You should leave in the class name if you feel like it. I was just making sure.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you need `proc` in rails 3.1, as given in the github issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/415 and also in other SO answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10620468/429850 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465800/429850